# Trying to convert pdf to text for free

Tags: macos

I am using OSX and would like to be able to convert pdf files to text.

I would like a free application to do this, as I am sure there must be some.

Comment: Are you looking to extract text from PDFs which already contain text?  (i.e., you could copy and paste pieces out of them) Or are you looking to recognize text that is in image content?

Comment: Does http://free-ocr.com help?

Answer (score 23):

Here are the steps I used to install and use xpdf via Homebrew.

1. Install Homebrew's dependencies:

```bash
xcode-select --install
```

2. Install Homebrew from their website:

```bash
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

3. Do what it tells you to complete the Homebrew installation.
4. Verify that Homebrew is happy and functioning to spec.

```bash
brew doctor
```

5. Next install xpdf and its dependencies:

```bash
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
brew install xpdf
```

6. Finally, use pdftotext, a package that comes with the xpdf suite:

```bash
pdftotext Some_Document.pdf Some_Document.txt
```

The first file name is an existing PDF; the second is the destination.  The results were much better than with an (admittedly old) version of Adobe Acrobat. Edit: New (2019) versions of Adobe Acrobat have shown similarly poor results.

Comment: I think the `xquartz` is not needed for the console tools in `xpdf`. Furthermore, there is the `poppler` fork of `xpdf` which seems far more actively maintained: https://github.com/scraperwiki/scraperwiki-python/issues/22#issuecomment-19201719

Comment: Worked great. Note that installing xpdf installed a *bunch* of dependencies on my system.

Comment: Tried and got a .txt with gibberish and U+000c is not a basic ASCIII character warning on one line when I ran pdftotext text.pdf text.txt . But perhaps pdf quality is just not good enough for conversion.

Answer (score 10):

Multiple methods.

1. Use [Google documents](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/12/convert-pdf-to-doc-free-with-google-docs/) (you will need a Google account)
2. Use [Automator](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030000207/http://www.macworld.com/article/1162699/business-software/how-to-convert-pdfs-to-word-and-other-formats.html) (some work required)

> You can use Automator to create a workflow that can extract text from
> PDFs and save it as a text or RTF document.

[image: extract text from pdf]

Answer (score 5):

`xpdf` which I installed with ports:

```
port install xpdf
```

contains:

```
xpdf-pdftotext
```

It does what you want for any PDF file which is coming from a
text file (and not from an image):

```
xpdf-pdftotext PDF_file text_file
```

Comment: The command, at least as installed by HomeBrew, is just “pdftotext”.

Comment: @FlashSheridan Can I encourage you to post an answer covering "pdftotext" and how to install it via homebrew? Comments may get deleted anytime (and also don't show up in searches).

Answer (score 4):

Current version of **Adobe Reader** (11.0.09) has a "Save as Other" item in its File Menu.

One of the options is **Text**.

The App is free, and does a decent job outputting text files. All images in the new document will be lost with the .txt format.

Answer (score 4):

The following python script will output the text from a PDF document to a .txt file. (Note: There is no guarantee that the text is necessarily in 'logical' human readable order, due to the way that data is held in the PDF format.)

The script will create text files for any PDF files supplied as arguments to it on the command line (e.g. `pdf2txt.py myPDF.pdf`), or you can use in Automator's "Run Shell Script" action, setting the shell type to *python* and *Pass input* to "As arguments". Then you can use it as a Quick Action or DropApp.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys
from Quartz import PDFDocument
from CoreFoundation import (NSURL, NSString)
NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4
    
def pdf2txt():
  for filename in sys.argv[1:]: 
    inputfile =filename.decode('utf-8')
    shortName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    outputfile = shortName+" text.txt"
    pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(inputfile)
    pdfDoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
    if pdfDoc :
      pdfString = NSString.stringWithString_(pdfDoc.string())
          pdfString.writeToFile_atomically_encoding_error_(outputfile, True, NSUTF8StringEncoding, None)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  pdf2txt()
```

NB: The above script will 'only' work on any Mac running Leopard to Monterey 12.2...! Python 2 was removed from macOS in Monterey 12.3. If you install python 3 and the pyobjc library, then the following python 3 script will work:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
import os, sys
from Quartz import PDFDocument
from CoreFoundation import (NSURL, NSString)
NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4
        
def pdf2txt():
  for filename in sys.argv[1:]: 
    shortName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    outputfile = shortName+" text.txt"
    pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filename)
    pdfDoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
    if pdfDoc:
      pdfString = NSString.stringWithString_(pdfDoc.string())
      pdfString.writeToFile_atomically_encoding_error_(outputfile, True, NSUTF8StringEncoding, None)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
  pdf2txt()
```

Comment: This works out of the box (ie - didnt have to install any python libraries or anything!) - Is just a raw dump of text, but sometimes that's what you need - note that the file saves in the current directory (if running from the command line) and doesnt come out to stdout

Comment: @BradParks It should save to the same folder as the input file: it takes the filepath from the command arguments. How are you supplying it?

Comment: ahh... i was in the same folder, so I never noticed that - my only real intent was to say that it doesnt come to stdout, and that it works! thanks!

Comment: Replace the two lines after the `if pdfDoc` statement with `print(pdfDoc.string())`.

Comment: Oh wow, this is like literally the first time ever that the Apple Python distribution turns out to be useful for something!! Thanks for the response!!

Comment: @Jérémie The built-in python (using the pyObjC library for accessing all the MacOS APIs) has been very useful since OS X Tiger, at least! Here's my complete suite of PDF utilities: https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite

Comment: The result for my test document was identical to manually selecting the entire document in Preview and copy and pasting it into a text editor, probably because the same framework is used.

Answer (score 3):

Using built-in **Shortcuts** app

1. Add "Get Text from PDF" action
2. Add "Append Text to <LOCATION>" action

[image: Shortcuts - Extract text from PDF]

Answer (score 2):

Extract selectable text (not OCR) in PDF on MacOS

`brew install poppler`

`pdftotext x.pdf x.txt`

Related:
[linux - Is the pdftotext command line tool for mac? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/56272/is-the-pdftotext-command-line-tool-for-mac)

Answer (score 1):

I would think you should be able to copy and paste the text into another document. To select all the text

#### Open the PDF in "Preview", and

- choose "Edit | Select All"
- choose "Edit | Copy"

#### Go to another app, say "Text Edit"

- choose "Edit | Paste"

Note that if you try and do this, and there's no text pasted, just a bunch of blank lines, try printing your PDF to a new PDF first, e.g.

- In Preview, choose "File | Print"
- In the bottom right, choose "PDF | Save as PDF"
- This exports a new PDF.

Now try the above process with this new PDF. Worked for me!

PS: If you have Microsoft Word, you may be able to [open your PDF in word](https://www.wikihow.com/Open-PDF-in-Word)

Comment: While this should work when the PDF document actually contains _text_ content, it does not maintain formatting and in some cases produces garbage text along with what would be considered wanted text. Note that this may also be the same with other methods, but I felt it important to point out.

Comment: without a doubt - not perfect for sure, and I totally agree with everything you've said. I only add it here as an option I've noticed before, that worked for me without installing anything at all ;-)

Comment: I also agree that it works for most cases, but page numbers, footer details that aren't related to the document and worse yet: INFINITE SCROLLING on large documents make this an unsatisfactory solution. If it was less than 5 pages I'd consider it, but given most tables I need are from PDFs off research sites that refuse to spit out excel or SQL, this option isn't even functional.

Comment: Agreed! not a viable option for your use case