# batch rename pdf files by content

Tags: command-line, macos

I have a big pile of pdf's and I would like to batch rename them by content. (They are all searchable). And I'd like to do so using command line interface.

They are all payslips so they have a constant form, and I'd like to rename by date.

Currently they are named: payslip100 .. payslip308

The string for renaming would be the date component in 
`Payment Date:   15/4/2016`

I have installed pdfgrep using home-brew and am searching using
`pdfgrep -HC 15 "Payment Date:" paySlip.pdf`

which returns `paySlip.pdf:Payment Date:   8/7/2016`

---

I have attached my final working code in a reply.

Comment: How do you perform search on PDFs?

Comment: I've just noticed that I can search the pdf's content using mdfind, which will give me the list of files containing a particular string.

`mdfind annual -onlyin ./`

But grep will not output any results from the same search.

`grep annual *.*`

Comment: So please update your question with the command you run and its results for a number of files. Then we can add commands to rename the files.

Comment: This is a long shot. What are the results of- `grep --binary-files=text 'Payment Date:'  file.pdf`? Where `file.pdf` is a single pdf file that you want to search.

Comment: `grep --binary-files=text 'Payment Date:' file.pdf` does not help. I'm thinking of trying pdftotext which I can apparently install using home-brew. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155250/trying-to-convert-pdf-to-text-for-free/155356.

Comment: Don't use `/` (unless you want to specify folders), use e.g. `_` or something similar instead.

Comment: @patrix, are you referring to payment date format? the slashes are already used in the pdf

Comment: Filenames are not allowed to contain forward slashes, because they are used to separate directories in a path name. Running `mv foo.txt bar/whatever.txt` will move the file to the directory `bar` (or fail it this directory doesn't exist), it will *not* rename the file to `bar/whatever.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

After some efforts I have come to a useful result !!
sed syntax is quite confusing and I am quite happy to exist in a state where it works without knowing quite why.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.pdf
do
    # return file name and date in form "Payment Date:   8/7/2016"
    date=$(pdfgrep -C 15 "Payment Date:" "$file")
    echo $date

    # now replace / with - to make naming file easier
    date2=$(echo "$date" | sed 's,/,-,g')
    echo $date2

    # use date string to rename : YYYY-mm-payslip-dd-mm-YYYY.pdf
    new=$(echo "$date2" | sed 's,\Payment Date:\ *\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\),\3-\2-\payslip-\1-\2-\3.pdf,')
    echo mv "$file" "$new"
done
```

I used pdfgrep which was installed using homebrew (found on another answer I can't find right now).

I needed to change "/" for file name.
Using the forward slash as sed syntax is not necessary, and can be replaced by other characters. Hence using "," instead of "/"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379293/replace-forward-slash-with-double-backslash-enclosed-in-double-quotes

I found there were variable spaces in $date which necessitated the `..Payment Date:\ *\...`

I added year and month to start of file name for organising purposes.